# Use XML Layout as view for View Subclass?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I feel as though I used to know how to do this, but I'm currently drawing a blank. I have a class that extends from View (`Card`) and I wrote a layout for it in XML. What I want to do is set the View of `Card` to be the XML View in the constructor, so I can use the methods in `Card` to set `TextView`s and whatnot. Any suggestions? Code below:

Card.java:
(I have `View.inflate(context, R.layout.card_layout, null);` there as an example of what I want to do, but it's not working. I basically want the class to be the interface for the View, and in order to do that I need to somehow assign the XML layout to the View. Do I use something along the lines of `setContentView(View view)`? There is no such method in the `View` class, but is there something like it?)

```
public class Card extends View {

    TextView tv;

    public Card(Context context) {
        super(context);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.card_layout, null);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.card_layout, null);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.card_layout, null);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        tv.setText(text);
    }

}
```

card_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="336dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/card_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible with the current setup. A `View`(or a direct subclass of it) represent a **single** view it doesn't have the notion of child views, what you're trying to do. The `LayoutInflater` can't be used with a simple `View` because the simple `View` class doesn't have the methods to actually add the child to it(like the `addView()` method).

On the other hand, the correct class to use to be able to have children is the `ViewGroup`(or one of the direct subclasses like `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout` etc) which accept adding `Views` or other `ViewGroups` to it, by supplying the `addView` methods. In the end your class should be:

```
public class Card extends ViewGroup {

    TextView tv;

    public Card(Context context) {
        super(context);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.card_layout, this);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.card_layout, this);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.card_layout, this);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        tv.setText(text);
    }

}
```

If I recall you have to override `onLayout` if you extend `ViewGroup`, so instead(and because of your layout file), you should look at extending `LinearLayout` and replace the `LinearLayout` from the xml layout with a `merge` tag.

Comment: I thought about just having my class extend `LinearLayout` and then thought it was a dumb idea. I tried it after seeing this comment and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use your class name in the layout. Something like:

```
<your.package.name.Card 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="336dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    ...
```

Just call `findViewById` to get child views.

To use your Card class, you use the inflator to get an instance, then attach it to a parent view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
Card card = (Card) inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_layout, null);
parentView.addView(card);
```

[Have a look at the docs for more info.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

Comment: But how is the `card_layout.xml` connected to the `Card` class? When I do what you wrote above, nothing appears.

Comment: I looked at the docs and it gives a lot of info on programmatically drawing a custom view but nothing on using one defined in XML. I could draw everything using methods and such, but it would take awhile, as it's a pretty detailed layout.

Comment: You will need to add an instance of `Card` to another view you are using either with `view.addView(card)` or with `setContentView(card)` for an activity.

Comment: Ok, well I guess you will need to use the inflator. I'll edit my answer to show how.